# The closed form solution of a point on a plane

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

Given a plane in 3D Euclidean space is  $\pi$: $ax+by+cz+d=0$
and a point $P$:$(X,Y,Z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$.

Find a point $Q:(X^*,Y^*,Z^*)\in \pi$ such that:

$$Q= \arg\min\limits_{Q^*\in\pi}\left\|P-Q\right\|$$

Is it difficult to find the closed form solution to $Q$?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not computational science.

Comment: Q is the orthogonal projection of P onto that plane, you should be able to find the formula quite easily.

Comment: This problem comes from computational geometry programming. Actually there is another similar problem from the same background: given two lines in 3D space, how to `numerically` determine whether they intersect or not.

Comment: @Dr_Sam do you have any clue in solving `orthogonal projection` of P?

Comment: That's another question then. For the projection, define the line orthogonal to $\pi$ passing by P (it's parallel to the normal direction of $\pi$). Then take the intersection of this line with the plane, and you have Q.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems this question is rather easy

Comment: Yes, this is easy :-)

Comment: How about my solution below in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a plane $\pi:  (a,b,c,d)$ , without loss of generality,  let $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, then the orthographic projection to $\pi$ in homogeneous matrix is:
$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1-a^2 & -a b & -a c & -a c \\
 -a b & 1-b^2 & -b c & -b c \\
 -a c & -b c & 1-c^2 & -c^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

If $P=(x,y,z,1)^T$, then the desired point $Q=T\cdot P$ is:
$$\left\{\quad
\begin{array}{c}
 \left(1-a^2\right) x-a b y-ac z -a c\\
-a b x+\left(1-b^2\right) y  -b c z-b c\\
-a x c-b cy+\left(1-c^2\right) z  -c^2\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Comment: The orthographic projection's homogeneous matrix is obtained from a concept `stereohomology`